# TThreadPoolServer or TTransportException Errors after enabling Kerberos in Hive

Tags: hive, kerberos

The following errors occur in the metastore or hiveserver after enabling Kerberos authentication.

- `ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message`
- `Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration HiveException: TTransportException`

HiveServer2 starts but will fail to connect to the `metastore` repeatedly even if it's running.
Each connection attempt is met with the above errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs if SASL is not properly enabled when `hive.server2.authentication` is set to `KERBEROS`

### Solution

set `hive.metastore.sasl.enabled` to `true` in `hive-site.xml`

also ensure `hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop` is set to one of the possible 3 options. eg. `auth`